# Sublimerge: 'Merge: left to right' grayed out, but 'Merge all: left to right' available

Tags: diff, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I'm using Sublime Text 3 with Sublimerge to compare files. I'm comparing files with the clipboard and I want to copy differences from left to right. I can see in the Sublimerge context menu that `Merge:Left to right` is unavailable/grayed out. However `Merge all:Left to right` is available to select.

How do I enable the option to `Merge:Left to right`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This option requires at least one change to be selected. Then it will become enabled. To select a change do one of the following:

1. Use context menu: Sublimerge -> Go to Next Change
2. Press 'ctrl' + 'alt' + '+'
3. Hold 'ctrl' + 'alt' and left click on one or more changes

Comment: Great! I was just highlighting the text and not understanding why I couldn't merge that  change.